# Midrashim on the people dying outside the ark

Tags: parashat-noach

Are there any midrashim that detail or say anything about the people outside the ark who were dying? Like their reactions maybe, or if they tried to get onto the ark, etc…

Comment: Doesn't it say they tried to force their way in when the flood started?

Comment: Yes, Rashi there, on Noach entered by the day. That many individuals came to kill Noach and Hashem showed that he was superior by allowing Noach to enter in broad daylight and no one being able to stop him

Comment: Also, it says Noach according to some, was not entirely sure the flood would happen until the water forces him inside the arc. So even Noach's reaction is somewhat suprising.